# Not getting user defined Arraylist in AlarmManager onReceive() method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, parcelable

This is common and frequently asked question in Android but still I am facing issue while sending user defined Arraylist/list using Parcelable.

I tried various way to send data to AlarmManager but finally not got success. Then come to know only implementing Parcelable, we can achieve this.

Below is my setAlarm method:

```
 public void startAlarm(View view) {
    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 3*60*1000;
    alarmIntent.putExtra("SAMPLE","Sample Data");
    alarmIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("DERIVATIVE_STOCK_LIST", derivativeStockEntityList); //(ArrayList<DerivativeStockEntity>)
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Derivative Stock Entity as Below:

```
@Entity
public class DerivativeStockEntity implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

private String name;
private String code;

public DerivativeStockEntity(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    code = in.readString();
}

public DerivativeStockEntity(int id, String name, String code) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(code);
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<DerivativeStockEntity> CREATOR = new Creator<DerivativeStockEntity>() {
    @Override
    public DerivativeStockEntity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DerivativeStockEntity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DerivativeStockEntity[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DerivativeStockEntity[size];
    }
};// Getter setter}
```

Code For BroadcastReveiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("i m running " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.context=context;
        ArrayList<DerivativeStockEntity> derivativeStockEntityList= intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("DERIVATIVE_STOCK_LIST");
    for(DerivativeStockEntity derivativeStockEntity:derivativeStockEntityList) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new OptionDataAlarmReceiver.FetchOptionDataThread(derivativeStockEntity.getCode()));
        thread.run();
    }
}
```

Here OnReceive() method I am trying to get DerivativeStockEntity list which I have passed from MainActivity, but getting Null pointer exception. I can get SAMPLE string but facing issue in List.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.